# jquerymobile split view right panel does not transition

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, ipad

I am using split view from the below link:

https://github.com/asyraf9/jquery-mobile/tree/gh-pages

When I click on the Demo button the menu page changes but the right panel is not changing as shown in the demo page. Could some one give some clues whats the issue ?

Below is the demo link:

http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that demo uses jQuery Mobile 1.0 Final (based on the date at the top of the JS include).

*You can ignore the rest if you are actually using jQuery Mobile 1.0 Final.*

In 1.0.1, jQuery Mobile moved to only using page-transitions for browsers less than `1000px` wide (I believe that's the number). In 1.1.0 this was altered to use only the `fade` transition for browsers with a screen-width that is too large.

This behavior has been added to jQuery Mobile because transitions usually look chunky on large screens (because so many pixels have to be drawn simultaneously).

> **Setting a max width for transitions**
>
> By default, transitions can be disabled (set to "none") when the
>   window width is greater than a certain pixel width. This feature is
>   useful because transitions can be distracting or perform poorly on
>   larger screens. This value is configurable via the global option
>   $.mobile.maxTransitionWidth, which defaults to false. The option
>   accepts any number representing a pixel width or false value. If it's
>   not false, the handler will use a "none" transition when the window
>   width is wider than the specified value.

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.2/docs/pages/page-transitions.html*